# Spring Data (JPA) context config XML - jpa:repositories

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I am creating a Spring MVC app in STS

In my JPA config XML I have the following error highlighted in STS

```
Error occured processing XML 'com/xxx/repository/ChannelProgrammeRepository : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0'. See Error Log for more details
```

For the line

```
<jpa:repositories base-package="com.xxx.repository"/>
```

My web.xml is set up like so

```
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:/jpaContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>SpringOpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>SpringOpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>xxxServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>classpath:/servlet-config.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>xxxServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

My jpaContext.xml has

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">


    <context:annotation-config />

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.xxx"/>    

    <jpa:repositories base-package="com.xxx.repository"/>
```

My Maven dependencies

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.thoughtworks.xstream</groupId>
        <artifactId>xstream</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.31</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.6.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
        <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.2.RELEASE</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions> 
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-path-assert</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

The `ChannelProgrammeRepository` interface it's complaining about

```
package com.xxx.repository;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import com.xxx.model.entity.ChannelProgramme;

public interface ChannelProgrammeRepository extends JpaRepository<ChannelProgramme, Long> {

}
```

A quick google seems to suggest the ChannelProgrammeRepository has been compiled with a different version of Java, or perhaps some conflict with one of my Maven dependencies?

Either way my project is set up to run with Java 7[image: build path]

Error in editor

[image: image1]

[image: image2]

Comment: Do you have a more complete stack trace from the error log?

Comment: There is nothing in the console, just a red cross whilst displaying the file in the editor. Screenshots added

Answer (score 1):

Please check, wich version your maven tries to compile the code to. Something in the properties section

```
<properties> 
    ...
    <targetJdk>1.7</targetJdk> 
    ...
</properties>
```

and then later

```
<plugin> 
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId> 
    <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version> 
    <configuration> 
        <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding> 
        <source>${targetJdk}</source> 
        <target>${targetJdk}</target> 
        <testSource>${targetJdk}</testSource> 
        <testTarget>${targetJdk}</testTarget> 
    </configuration> 
</plugin>
```

perhaps the target is set to 6.0 or earlier. Then the compiler will be called to compile for/with 6.0 and this failure can be thrown.

Set the target and source to 7.0 and it should work ...

Comment: In the pom.xml? I see none of that in mine, no <properties> or <plugin>

Comment: try mvn help:effective-pom and then look for it. It has to be at least 1.7 to load classes with level 51.0. If it is 1.6 or below, then you should add something like the text above.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think anything wrong wiht your jpa configuration. Its certainly because of a mismatch in Compilation Level used in Eclipse or IDE. You can try chaning the Compiler Compliance Level, do clean build.

Usually we get UnsupportedClassVersionError when we use a higher JDK verion at compile time and lower JDK version at runtime.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try a clean build,

```
Project -> Clean
```

It removes whatever already-compiled files are in your project so that you can do a complete fresh rebuild. Thus getting rid of the error in the config file.